# SPARK SQL : How to convert List[List[Any]) to Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val list = List(List(1,"Ankita"),List(2,"Kunal"))
```

and now I want to convert it into the data frame -

```
 val list = List(List(1,"Ankita"),List(2,"Kunal")).toDF("id","name")
```

but it throws an error -

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Scala.any

Comment: val list = List(List(1,"Ankita"),List(2,"Kunal")) -- writing this , I get List[List[Any] ... Please help me out whats wrong then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `List[List[Any]]` cannot be converted to DataFrame directly, It need to convert to some type (here I took example to Person) `List[Person]`

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)

val list = List(List(1,"Ankita"),List(2,"Kunal"))

val listDf = list.map(x => Person(x(0).asInstanceOf[Int], x(1).toString)).toDF("id","name")
```

---

Another way is per the comment of [user8371915](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8371915/user8371915), Create list of pairs and convert to DataFrame

```
val listDf = list.map { 
  case List(id: Int, name: String) => (id, name) } toDF("id", "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because List (inside List) can be arbitrary size and can not using implicit type conversion.
It can be converted if you change to List of Tuple.

```
val list = List((1,"Ankita"),(2,"Kunal")).toDF("id","name")
```